# Can we implement .NET interfaces in PowerShell scripts?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, powershell-3.0

Lets say we have a few interfaces defined in a .NET class library written in C#. Is there a way to implement these interfaces in a PowerShell script?

Call this a business need. We as a vendor, provide a few interfaces that are implemented by our customers to use our product. One of our customer wants to do this from PowerShell script.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? PowerShell is dynamically typed itself.

Comment: @poke don't see what this has to do with his question, implementing an interface doesn't have anything to do with powershell's typing, maybe he needs to pass his objects to a .net method that expects an IEnumerable<HisInterface> for example

Comment: @RonanThibaudau My question has to do with finding out about the [X of this Y](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @poke our customer wants to implement our interfaces in their PowerShell scripts. No one ever asked this before.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Powershell. Create a class file to hold Custom Objects?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18705158/powershell-create-a-class-file-to-hold-custom-objects)

Comment: related: [can INotifyPropertyChanged be implemented natively?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/21814444/33499) and [Does PowerShell support OOP?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/683811/33499)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's a simple example with PowerShell 5.0 implementing the .Net *IEqualityComparer* interface:

```
Class A:System.Collections.IEqualityComparer {
  [bool]Equals($x,$y)  { return $x -eq $y        }
  [int]GetHashCode($x) { return $x.GetHashCode() }
}
[A]$a=[A]::new()
$a.Equals(1,1) -- returns True
$a.Equals(1,2) -- returns False
$a.GetHashCode("OK") -- returns 2041362128
```

You could even have a class (called A), which inherits from another class (called B) and implements IEqualityComparer:

```
Class A:B,System.Collections.IEqualityComparer {
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Add-Type` to define the class in C#, JScript, or VBScript.  When there's a vendor-supplied assembly involved, it just has to be loaded prior to the `Add-Type` call, with another call to `Add-Type`:

```
$sourceCode = @"
    public class CustomerClass : Vendor.Interface
    {
         public bool BooleanProperty { get; set; }
         public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    }
"@    # this here-string terminator needs to be at column zero

$assemblyPath = 'C:\Path\To\Vendor.dll'
Add-Type -LiteralPath $assemblyPath
Add-Type -TypeDefinition $sourceCode -Language CSharp -ReferencedAssemblies $assemblyPath

$object = New-Object CustomerClass
$object.StringProperty = "Use the class"
```

Answer (score 5):

**EDIT: It seems you can now [implement interfaces in powershell 5.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-windows-powershell-50?view=powershell-6#new-features-in-windows-powershell-50). This answer applies to powershell 4.0 or earlier.**

Although you cannot implement interface from powershell directly, you can pass [powershell delegates to .NET code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10995667/lambda-expression-in-powershell). You could provide empty implementation of interface accepting delegates in constructor, and construct this object from powershell:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    void Bar();
}

public class FooImpl : IFoo
{
    Action bar_;
    public FooImpl(Action bar)
    {
        bar_ = bar;
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        bar_();
    }
}
```

And in powershell:

```
$bar = 
{ 
   Write-Host "Hello world!"
}

$foo = New-Object FooImpl -ArgumentList $bar
# pass foo to other .NET code
```