# throwing more than one custom exception in powershell

Tags: powershell, exception

I have a situation where i have to throw multiple custom exceptions in a try block in my powershell script something like below

```
try {
    if (!$condition1) {
        throw [MyCustomException1] "Error1"
    }
    if (!$condition2) {
        throw [MyCustomException2] "Error2"
    }
}catch [MyCustomException1] {
    #do some business logic
}catch [MyCustomException2] {
    #do some other business logic
}catch{
    #do something else
}
```

Is there a way to do it in powershell without writing the .net class `MyCustomException1` and `MyCustomException2`. I don't have to store any info in the class but i just need a way to differentiate the exceptions. 
I could do as below but i just wondering if something cleaner.

```
try {
    if (!$condition1) {
        throw "Error1"
    }
    if (!$condition2) {
        throw "Error2"
    }
}catch {
    if($_.tostring() -eq "Error1"){
        Write-Host "first exception"
    }elseif($_.tostring() -eq "Error2"){
        Write-Host "Second exception"
    }else {
        Write-Host "third exception"
    }
}
```

Note: I have already checked below stack overflow questions: [powershell-creating-a-custom-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703180/powershell-creating-a-custom-exception) [powershell-2-0-try-catch-how-to-access-the-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182666/powershell-2-0-try-catch-how-to-access-the-exception)  [powershell-creating-and-throwing-new-exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11981208/powershell-creating-and-throwing-new-exception)  But it doesn't answer my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Thanks @BenH and @TheIncorrigible1 for your pointers on creating classes and Exceptions. Below is a sample code to achieve this if some one else also looking for the same.

```
class MyEXCP1: System.Exception{
    $Emessage
    MyEXCP1([string]$msg){
        $this.Emessage=$msg
    }
}
class MyEXCP2: System.Exception{
    $Emessage
    MyEXCP2([string]$msg){
        $this.Emessage=$msg
    }
}
$var=2
try{
    if($var -eq 1){
        throw [MyEXCP1]"Exception 1"
    }
    if($var -eq 2){
        throw [MyEXCP2]"Exception 2"
    }
}catch [MyEXCP1]{
    Write-Output "Exception 1 thrown"
}catch [MyEXCP2]{
    Write-Output "Exception 2 thrown"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could look at the `FullyQualifiedErrorID` property on the `$error` variable to get the string from the `throw` statement.

```
try {throw "b"}
catch {
    if ($error[0].FullyQualifiedErrorID -eq "a") {'You found error "a"'}
    if ($error[0].FullyQualifiedErrorID -eq "b") {'You found error "b"'}
}
```

But it looks like you don't really want to `Try` `Catch` but to make non-terminating errors. You could use `Write-Error` to do this.

```
if (!$condition1) {
    Write-Error "Error1"
}
if (!$condition2) {
    Write-Error "Error2"
}
```

Comment: i would like to catch the errors in different catch blocks instead of one catch block and then putting if conditions.
I need to perform some business logic in the catch blocks. To make the question simple i just put the write-host statements

Comment: @Pramod You get one `catch` per error type, but you stated you didn't want to make error types.

Comment: Yes i just want to know if there is any way to get one `catch` block per error type without creating `.net` classes for `MyCustomException1` and `MyCustomException2`.

Comment: @pramod There are plenty of builtin types. [System.Management.Automation.CommandNotFoundException], [System.SystemException],[System.Net.WebException],[System.IO.IOException] are just the few straight from [about_try_catch_finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.0/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally) if you don't want to use pre-made types then use you would need to create the type...

Comment: @Pramod This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59819/how-do-i-create-a-custom-type-in-powershell-for-my-scripts-to-use) also may be helpful on how to create classes in PowerShell

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize [$PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.cmdlet.throwterminatingerror(v=vs.85).aspx) and define your own ErrorRecord object.

Here's [another useful article](https://kevinmarquette.github.io/2017-04-10-Powershell-exceptions-everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know/#pscmdletthrowterminatingerror) on error handling in PowerShell.

For your question on custom classes, you can also utilize your own classes in PSv5+

---

After reading your comments, you can figure out *which errors* you want to handle by using:

```
Catch { "[$($_.Exception.GetType().FullName)]" }
```

This gives you the class of error that is being thrown.  Paired with:

```
Catch { $_.Exception.Message }
```

You can also see what the system is reporting.

Answer (score -1):

I was just trying to find something really basic for error treatment and I came up with this:

```
try {
    $a = 1
    if($a-eq1) { throw "OneException" }
    if($a-eq2) { throw "TwoException" }
} catch {
    switch ($error[0]){
        "OneException" { echo "one" }
        "TwoException" { echo "two" }
        default { echo $_.Exception }
    }
}
```

Not fancy, but functional :)

Comment: This is the same as what the question proposes except you've simplified the `if...elseif...` to a `switch`.  By doing it this way you lose the ability to have a `catch` block for each `Exception` type.

Comment: I Agree with Lance. This is -to me- an example of bad programming and not making use of provided language features.